# How can i get only keys from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a structure of database as on image and I need to display this date which is in the red rectangle. I tried to do smth like this, but it throws an error and I couldn't find same questions on a stack.

my database

[image]

```
reference.child("doc1").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                for date in (snapshot.value?.allKeys)
            }
```

Comment: What was the error ?

Comment: The problem was in casting, it should be casted to Any?. I've fixed it, doing smth like this:
for date in ((snapshot.value as AnyObject).allKeys) {
                        self.workDays.append(snapshot.value as! String)
                    }
                    print(self.workDays)
And now i get an error in console : "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x11191f218) to 'NSString' (0x110d5dd68)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is a Dictionary of Dictionary so you have to cast your snap to `[String:[String:Any]]` where the key is your "11dot..." and value contains all hours

So try to use this code:

```
guard let dict = snap.value as? [String:[String:Any]] else { return }
for (key, value) in dict {
    for (key2, value2) in value {
        print(key2, value2) // this print your hours
    }
}
```

Anyway I suggest you to don't use a observe(.value) which will read all change happened on all child node. Instead use the `.childAdded` feature of observer.

With a `.childAdded` you will receive only one child at a time (like a for on child node) and after that only the child added:

```
Database.database().reference().child("doc1").observe(.childAdded) { (snap) in
    guard let dict = snap.value as? [String:Any]
    print(dict) // this print data contains on "11dot10" and so on  
}
```

Comment: It needs an else condition after guard

Comment: you are right @leznevo100, fixed. Anyway this help you?

Comment: Yeah, but i think it will be more convenient to use simple array here. Anyway thnx.