# Pull firebase data that doesn't have key

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an iOS workout split app with firebase RT database as the backend. At the moment, I'm storing the data on all the workouts like this is firebase:

```
{
  "DuGjwAxKwScYFiWK4xx1IsATfsC2" : {
    "splits" : {
      "Test-Split" : {
        "day 1" : {
          "-MhjCRcr8Wv7HrIF8Ico" : {
            "Exercise Name" : "Curls",
            "Is Timed" : false,
            "Reps or Secs" : "12",
            "Sets" : "4"
          },
        }
      },
      "Test-Split-2" : {
        "day 1" : {
          "-MhjC_FAIrYLD907KmXY" : {
            "Exercise Name" : "Squats",
            "Is Timed" : false,
            "Reps or Secs" : "12",
            "Sets" : "4"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

What I'm looking to do at the moment is pull just the names of the splits, so that a user can select which split they want to run. In the above example, the split names are Test-Split and Test-Split-2. The trouble is, they don't have any kind of key associated with them. I can pull a snapshot that will give me all the data downstream of "splits", but how do I just pull the split names?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it could work. There he got a lot of people telling him his data was overly nested. Does my structure here have a similar problem? I'm still very new to firebase so I don't want to get into any bad habits. If it does, what would be a better way to structure this database?

Comment: If you only want to get the keys (`Test-Split`, `Test-Split-2`) and not the underlying values, the only way to do so is through the REST API and its `shallow=true` parameter (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/37365866). No such option exists in the SDKS, and as Dhararaj commented, the common workaround is to have a separate top-level node where you have only the keys (typically with a marker value of `true`, since keys must have a value to exist). If you want to get all data, but only print the keys, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46345639 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50849420

Comment: You just cannot fetch the keys only. The best option would be to use the REST API Shallow queries https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-param-shallow run a query on splits node but it'll return an object with split IDs like this: `{splits: {split1: true, split2: true}}`